# Flutter App crashing after Splash Screen - Android and IOS Simulators

Tags: android, flutter, dart

App is crashing after splash screen. I use Android Studio on a MacBook.

Below are the details of flutter run logs for Android and IOS along with flutter doctor and flutter run --verbose

**FLUTTER RUN (ANDROID) :** The logs get stuck after the last line and nothing happens even after an hour.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: /Users/rohitchaudhari/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/rohitchaudhari/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.4.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/urllauncher/WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/rohitchaudhari/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player-0.10.11+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/videoplayer/VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/rohitchaudhari/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.22+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/FlutterWebView.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
```

**FLUTTER RUN (IOS) :** The logs get stuck after the last line and nothing happens even after an hour.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             19.3s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           949.6s
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ba89b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cd4c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488e2273 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 491
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488e3237 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 147
    5   Flutter                             0x000000011171ef53 -[FlutterViewController splashScreenFromXib:] + 66
    6   Flutter          <…>
This is taking longer than expected...
```

**FLUTTER DOCTOR :**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

**XCODE RUN ERRORS (Debug Mode) :**

```
2020-06-19 17:04:50.594270+0530 Runner[28755:186463] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:57856/ZA1msGYhRVI=/
2020-06-19 17:04:50.698101+0530 Runner[28755:185769] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/rohitchaudhari/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E5D00A1A-5ED7-4263-8745-182DADC3A4A7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/95E8F966-4520-44FD-BDD5-79E20450BF5B/Runner.app> (loaded)' with name 'LaunchScreen''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ba89b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cd4c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488e2273 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 491
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488e3237 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 147
    5   Flutter                             0x000000010e5ecf53 -[FlutterViewController splashScreenFromXib:] + 66
    6   Flutter                             0x000000010e5ece83 -[FlutterViewController loadDefaultSplashScreenView] + 115
    7   Flutter                             0x000000010e5ebdc4 -[FlutterViewController initWithProject:nibName:bundle:] + 369
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488e0707 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2427
    9   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff48107274 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 743
    10  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff48106f80 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 251
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488e499a -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 125
    12  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff48107274 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 743
    13  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff48107518 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1419
    14  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff48106f80 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 251
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488df7d5 -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 450
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488e24e8 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1120
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48e0489f -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 279
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48e0474a -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 97
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c8ab8d -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 167
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c8b122 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 274
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c89af3 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 964
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839225d -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4889dcc1 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 83
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48392d6f __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839277e -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 296
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48392b9c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 818
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48392431 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 345
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48396a22 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff487b3dad +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 852
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488bc41e _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 240
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839673d __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 153
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff488bc321 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 84
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff483965ab -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 381
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff481eafa8 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 657
    35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff481e9b67 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 253
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff481eacd2 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 210
    37  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c88141 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 512
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff487da8dc -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    39  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cacd2e -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 419
    40  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cd2dc1 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 102
    41  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cb7757 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220
    42  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cd2a52 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 355
    43  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112e72e8e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    44  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112e75da2 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    45  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cf86e9 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    46  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cf83d7 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    47  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cf88e6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    48  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da0d31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    49  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da0c5c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    50  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da0434 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    51  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b02e __CFRunLoopRun + 974
    52  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9a944 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    53  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38ba6c1a GSEventRunModal + 139
    54  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c8b9ec UIApplicationMain + 1605
    55  Runner                              0x000000010beddb6b main + 75
    56  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff51a231fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**FLUTTER RUN --VERBOSE (Error) :**

```
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:336:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:703:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:620:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart)
#5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29)
#6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
#7      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#8      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1619:10)
#9      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1539:10)
#10     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18)
#11     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:610:20)
#12     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
#13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:339:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart)
#15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29)
#16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
#17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#18     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1619:10)
#19     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1539:10)
#20     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18)
#21     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:19)
#22     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#23     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#24     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#25     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:231:18)
#26     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:22)
#27     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
#28     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#29     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1619:10)
#30     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1608:12)
#31     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1536:12)
#32     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#33     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart)
#34     runInContext.runnerWrapper (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:64:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#35     runInContext.runnerWrapper (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart)
#36     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29)
#37     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
#38     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#39     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1619:10)
#40     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1539:10)
#41     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18)
#42     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:67:24)
#43     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:48:10)
#44     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:69:9)
#45     main (file:///b/s/w/ir/k/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#46     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#47     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Comment: Can you run the app with xcode? you might get a more helpful log by doing that

Comment: Update the XCode error logs, please check

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved the X-Code logs showed that the LaunchScreen was incorrect, changed the LaunchScreen storyboard and the app loaded.

Comment: could you elaborate on this at all? What was wrong with your launch screen?